# k2.3.4 how do I pass variables through function index() in controller

Tags: kohana

I'm using **Kohana 2.3.4**.

How do I pass variables through the function index() in controller? I don't want to create another function to pass variables.

I prefer this `www.web.com/article/1` **instead of** `www.web.com/article/view/1`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've worked with Kohana 2.3.4, but you need routing to help you out here. Straight from the documentation:

[Routing - Kohana 2.3.4](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/routing)

```
$config['article/([0-9]+)'] = 'news/show/$1';
```

> which would match URIs starting with “article/” followed by some numeric digits. If the URI takes this form, we will use the news controller and call it's show() method passing in the article number as the first argument.

You'll need to tweak the value of your config item, so instead of using the show action you'd use index.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!. This is my first time to understand about the URIs stuff.